# Spyder does not run in Conda environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, spyder

I tried to create an environment called badlands_env, I activated the environment and in it I tried to run sypder. It launches but as soon as I try to import package of the environment I get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'badlands'

How can I fix it?

I tried to download spyder outside the environment to see if this fix it but It won't launch.

Comment: You need to show the full traceback

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.